# How I can get the right data for specific user when I did auth flow (log in, log out) with Flutter Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-getx

Here is my stream to get data from firebase inside Flutter

```
Stream<List<TodoModel>> todoStream(String uid) {
return _firestore
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("todos")
    .orderBy("dateCreated", descending: true)
    // .where("done", isEqualTo: true)
    .snapshots()
    .map((QuerySnapshot query) {
  List<TodoModel> retVal = [];
  for (var element in query.docs) {
    retVal.add(TodoModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(element));
  }
  return retVal;
});
```

Here is homeController

```
  Rxn<List<TodoModel>> todoList = Rxn<List<TodoModel>>();

  var selectedDate = DateTime.now().obs;

  List<TodoModel>? get todos => todoList.value;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    String uid = Get.find<AuthController>().user.value?.uid ?? ' ';
    todoList.bindStream(Database().todoStream(uid));
    super.onInit();
  }

  chooseDate() async {
    DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: Get.context!,
      initialDate: selectedDate.value,
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime(2024),
      //initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.input,
      // initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.year,
    );
    if (pickedDate != null && pickedDate != selectedDate.value) {
      selectedDate.value = pickedDate;
    }
  }
}
```

And from home view, I called to get data from firestore.

```
GetX<HomeController>(
                  init: Get.put<HomeController>(HomeController()),
                  builder: (HomeController todoController) {
                    if (todoController.todos != null) {
                      // print(todoController.todos?.done ?? false);
                      return Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: todoController.todos?.length,
                          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                            return TodoCard(
                              uid: controller.user.value?.uid ?? ' ',
                              todo: todoController.todos![index],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Text("loading...");
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

And I get the data for specific users but only the first time when I open my app. When I tried to log out and log in with a new user I get the data from the previous user. I checked and it's not a problem with SignOut functions from firestore, I think it's a problem with reactive snapshot because I got the right snapshot for a specific user but only if I restarted my app and try to log in. So can someone help with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without seeing the AuthController difficult to tell.

`Get.find<AuthController>().user.value?.uid ?? ' ';`

You can replace this with `FirebaseAuth.instace.currentUser.uid`